# Как разделить список в Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу понять как разделить список на списки.
Код:

```
a = [[-3, 0, -6, -6, -3], [8, 2, -2, -1, -8], [-9, 9, 6, -4, -4], [4, -4, 5, -3, -8], \
     [4, -1, 2, -6, -3], [9, -4, 8, -9, 0]]

print('Матрица:')
for i in a:
    print(*i)

for i in a:
    for m in i:
        if m > 0:
            m *= 2
            x.append(m)
        else:
            x.append(m)
```

Выходит:

```
x = [-3, 0, -6, -6, -3, 16, 4, -2, -1, -8, -9, 18, 12, -4, -4, 8, -4, 10, -3, -8, 8, -1, 4, -6, -3, 18, -4, 16, -9, 0]
```

Должно быть:

```
x = [[-3, 0, -6, -6, -3], [16, 4, -2, -1, -8], [-9, 18, 12, -4, -4], [8, -4, 10, -3, -8], [8, -1, 4, -6, -3], [18, -4, 16, -9, 0]]
```

P.S.
По программе def мы еще не знаем

Comment: Извиняюсь! Исправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

последний два цикла замените на:

```
for i in a:
    x.append([])
    for m in i:
        if m > 0:
            m *= 2
            x[-1].append(m)
        else:
            x[-1].append(m)
```

И место

```
if m > 0:
    m *= 2
    x[-1].append(m)
else:
    x[-1].append(m)
```

лучше писать

```
if m > 0:
    m *= 2
x[-1].append(m)
```

---

Это можно легко решить с помощью list comprehension

```
x = [[m * 2 if m > 0 else m
    for m in i]
    for i in a]
```

Comment: Оххх, спасибо вам большое! А всего лишь надо было мелочь добавить.